# how to parse the JSON object in salesforce

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

how to parse the json string . here multiple contact,multiple postalcode and mulitple contactnumber .how can i get the values from this json output.like list of contacts,list of postalcode and list of contactnumber.

```
{
    "CompanyContacts": [
        {
            "contact": "pn0",
            "postalcode": "0",
            "contactnumber": "pc0"
        },
        {
            "contact": "pn1",
            "postalcode": "1",
            "contactnumber": "pc1"
        },
        {
            "contact": "pn2",
            "postalcode": "2",
            "contactnumber": "pc2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at `JSON.deserialize();` ([documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_json.htm))

In your case, what you will have to do is create 2 inner classes like so:

```
public class CompanyContacts
{
     public List<CompanyContactsWrapper> CompanyContacts;
}

public class CompanyContactsWrapper
{
     public String contact;
     public String postalcode;
     public String contactnumber;
}
```

then deserialize your JSON string in a new instace of the classes you created.

```
CompanyContacts companycontacts = (CompanyContacts)JSON.deserialize(jsonstring, CompanyContacts.class);
```

now you'll be able to programatically approach the values of your json string in the new list.

Comment: Thanks PJC for your response... i tried what  you said i got out put like this from this out put how to get the list<contact>,list<postalcode> and list<contactnumber> pls help how to solve this problem... output:
CompanyContacts:

[CompanyContacts=(CompanyContactsWrapper:[postalcode=1, contact=pn1, contactnumber=pc1], 

           CompanyContactsWrapper:[postalcode=, contact=, contactnumber=],

           CompanyContactsWrapper:[postalcode=, contact=, contactnumber=])

]
Thanks

Comment: you just loop over your list:
for(CompanyContactsWrapper wrapper : companycontacts.CompanyContacts){
wrapper.contact;
wrapper.postalcode;} then you can do whatever you want with that data, put it in other lists, make contacts, whatever ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable input to resolve our constrains..Thanks

Comment: @Kittu Good Question

Answer (score 9):

The easiest solution (and most efficient in terms of script statements!) is going to be for you to head to [Json2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/makeApex) (written by metadaddy and superfell), plug your JSON in, and away you go!

That will spit out this class:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class CompanyContactsParser {

public class CompanyContacts {
    public String contact;
    public String postalcode;
    public String contactnumber;
}

public List<CompanyContacts> CompanyContacts;


public static CompanyContactsParser parse(String json) {
    return (CompanyContactsParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CompanyContactsParser.class);
}

static testMethod void testParse() {
    String json = '{'+
    '    \"CompanyContacts\": ['+
    '        {'+
    '            \"contact\": \"pn0\",'+
    '            \"postalcode\": \"0\",'+
    '            \"contactnumber\": \"pc0\"'+
    '        },'+
    '        {'+
    '            \"contact\": \"pn1\",'+
    '            \"postalcode\": \"1\",'+
    '            \"contactnumber\": \"pc1\"'+
    '        },'+
    '        {'+
    '            \"contact\": \"pn2\",'+
    '            \"postalcode\": \"2\",'+
    '            \"contactnumber\": \"pc2\"'+
    '        }'+
    '    ]'+
    '}';
    CompanyContactsParser obj = parse(json);
    System.assert(obj != null);
    }
}
```

The alternative would be using the [JSONParser](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_json.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_json.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), but this will chew up a LOT of script statements quickly if you have a lot of data, and is also fairly hard to read and maintain

Answer (score 3):

Suman,
Your json looks like it has an array of contact,postalcode,contactnumber.

Suppose you get the json from an http response:

```
HttpResponse resp = h.send(req);
```

You can start parsing it as below:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = JSON.createParser(resp.getBody());
 while(jsonParser.nextToken() != null){

 if(jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY ){
          while(jsonParser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY){
            if((jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(jsonParser.getText() == 'Key')){
               jsonParser.nextToken();
              if(jsonParser.getText()== 'Token1'){
                  jsonParser.nextToken();
               if(jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(jsonParser.getText() == 'Value')){
                 jsonParser.nextToken();
                 uploadToken = jsonParser.getText();
                             }
                 }else if(jsonParser.getText()== 'Token2'){
                      jsonParser.nextToken();
                 if((jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(jsonParser.getText() == 'Value')){
                      jsonParser.nextToken();
                      destFolderPath = jsonParser.getText();
                     }
                  }
                  }
                  }
                  }
```

Note that here, I'm only interested in getting the values of the two tokens. You can put this inside a loop and get all the values in a list just as easily.

Here's the json I parsed using the above code:

```
"paramList": [
                              {
                                        "Key": "Token1",
                                        "Value": "xyz"
                              },
                              {
                                        "Key": "Token2",
                                        "Value": "abc"
                              }
                    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone wants a JSON parsing utility to just extract one or a few values without deserializing to a class then check out

https://github.com/Trigger2991/SFDC-JSON-Parser

It allows you to parse a JSON string and then extract the value of any key you request. Great when calling an API that returns many values and you only want one or two.